# matlab: detecting better branchpoints from skeleton

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I have two skeleton images over which I extracted the branchpoints. Unfortunately, the branchpoints do not seem to be correct. Does anyone has a suggestion on how to extract valid branchpoints (i.e. "y"-like shape points)?

```
reg1 = imread('region1.tif');
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(reg1), find(bwmorph(reg1,'branchpoint') == 1)); 
h=figure; imshow(reg1); hold on; plot(j,i,'rx');print(h,'reg1overlay','-dtiff');
```

In the first example below there should be only **one** branchpoint:

[image: Region 1 original image]
[image: Region 1 overlay]

```
reg2 = imread('region2.tif');
[i,j] = ind2sub(size(reg2), find(bwmorph(reg2,'branchpoint') == 1)); 
h=figure; imshow(reg2); hold on; plot(j,i,'rx');print(h,'reg2overlay','-dtiff');
```

In the second example below there should be only **no** branchpoints:

[image: Region 2 original image]
[image: Region 2 overlay]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
branchskel = bwmorph(BW,'skel',Inf); %BW is your binarized image
branchskel = bwmorph(branchskel,'thin'); %this should remove those pixel piles that are giving you problems
B = bwmorph(branchskel, 'branchpoints');
[yb,xb] = find(B);
```